# how do we enable Send by Email function in HP ALM 11.0?

Tags: hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I am attempting to decipher how I can enable the "Send by Email button in the defects section of HP ALM 11.0. We have three environments, Production, Certification, and Test/Development. PROD and CERT have this disabled, but it is enabled in Test/DEV. It appears that my company's vendor support did this last year during our upgrade. Thus none of my team knows where to look, and information found on HP's support site is cryptic at best. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discovered the answer to this question. Here it is:

Note: These steps can only be performed by a project admin

1. Log into HP ALM Quality Center v 11.0
2. Select and access the intended project
3. Select the "Defects" tab is the left-hand column
4. Click the "Tools" drop-down
5. Select "Customize" to access the Project Customization screen
6. Select "Workflow" from the list
7. Click "Script Editor" to open the Scrips Editor screen
8. Make sure "Common Script" is selected
9. Search for and disable the following code in the common script:

   If InStr(ActionName, "act-SendbyEmail") > 0 Or _

   ActionName = "act_followup" Or _

   InStr(ActionName, "act_mail_tests") > 0 Then

   ```
    MsgBox "This function is currently disabeled."

    ActionCanExecute = False
   ```

   End If
10. Save the script and exit the Script Editor

This should do the trick. Good luck.